# Migration of Metabase from H2 db to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, h2, metabase

The current metabase h2 database runs fine on v0.44.6. However, when I upgrade Metabase to the latest or attempt migrating to postgreSQL I get the following error. Can you please help? Thanks

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 315043, expected page length 4..768, got -822014074 [1.4.197/6]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM metabase_field ORDER BY id ASC [50000-197]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:307)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:216)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:114)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$execute_query_with_params.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1090)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$execute_query_with_params.invoke(jdbc.clj:1084)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1106)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:1093)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$reducible_query$reify__28563.reduce(jdbc.clj:1357)
        at clojure.core$transduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6946)
        at clojure.core$transduce.invoke(core.clj:6933)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$copy_data_BANG_.invokeStatic(copy.clj:172)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$copy_data_BANG_.invoke(copy.clj:164)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$fn__82002$copy_BANG___82007$fn__82008$fn__82017$fn__82018$fn__82019.invoke(copy.clj:359)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$do_with_disabled_db_constraints.invokeStatic(copy.clj:264)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$do_with_disabled_db_constraints.invoke(copy.clj:260)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$fn__82002$copy_BANG___82007$fn__82008$fn__82017$fn__82018.invoke(copy.clj:358)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$do_with_connection_rollback_only.invokeStatic(copy.clj:206)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$do_with_connection_rollback_only.invoke(copy.clj:204)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$fn__82002$copy_BANG___82007$fn__82008$fn__82017.invoke(copy.clj:356)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:807)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:776)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:852)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:776)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:789)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:776)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$fn__82002$copy_BANG___82007$fn__82008.invoke(copy.clj:353)
        at metabase.cmd.copy$fn__82002$copy_BANG___82007.invoke(copy.clj:331)
        at metabase.cmd.load_from_h2$load_from_h2_BANG_.invokeStatic(load_from_h2.clj:35)
        at metabase.cmd.load_from_h2$load_from_h2_BANG_.invoke(load_from_h2.clj:25)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:384)
        at metabase.cmd$load_from_h2.invokeStatic(cmd.clj:45)
        at metabase.cmd$load_from_h2.invoke(cmd.clj:39)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:662)
        at metabase.cmd$run_cmd$fn__82799.invoke(cmd.clj:227)
        at metabase.cmd$run_cmd.invokeStatic(cmd.clj:227)
        at metabase.cmd$run_cmd.invoke(cmd.clj:218)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:388)
        at metabase.core$run_cmd.invokeStatic(core.clj:160)
        at metabase.core$run_cmd.invoke(core.clj:158)
        at metabase.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:182)
        at metabase.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:177)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at metabase.core.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 315043, expected page length 4..768, got -822014074 [1.4.197/6]
        at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:870)
        at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:652)
        at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:186)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:1936)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:698)
        at org.h2.mvstore.Page.getChildPage(Page.java:208)
        at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.fetchNext(Cursor.java:150)
        at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.next(Cursor.java:50)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap$2.fetchNext(TransactionStore.java:1509)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap$2.next(TransactionStore.java:1559)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap$2.next(TransactionStore.java:1494)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex$MVStoreCursor.next(MVPrimaryIndex.java:404)
        at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.next(IndexCursor.java:316)
        at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:502)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select$LazyResultQueryFlat.fetchNextRow(Select.java:1452)
        at org.h2.result.LazyResult.hasNext(LazyResult.java:79)
        at org.h2.result.LazyResult.next(LazyResult.java:59)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:527)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:633)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.queryWithoutCacheLazyCheck(Query.java:114)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:371)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:333)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:114)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:202)
        ... 44 more
Command failed with exception: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 315043, expected page length 4..768, got -822014074 [1.4.197/6]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM metabase_field ORDER BY id ASC [50000-197]
```